# Getting error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, numpy, ocr

I am getting this error when I want the gray image to display in vs code, i am unable to fix it.

Error:

```
 File "d:\OCR_PYTHON\opencv1.py", line 57, in <module>
    display("temp/gray.jpg")
  File "d:\OCR_PYTHON\opencv1.py", line 21, in display     
-->   height, width, depth = im_data.shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Code:

```py
from turtle import width
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_file = "data/image.jpg"


#Display Image

#size will not be good to fit in screen

img = cv.imread(image_file)

#cv.imshow("Original image",img)
#cv.waitKey(0)

#for Best size


def display(im_path):
    
    dpi = 80

    im_data = plt.imread(im_path)

    height, width, depth = im_data.shape

#what size dose the figure need to be in inches to fit the image

    figsize = width/float(dpi), height/float(dpi)

#Creat a figure of the riht size with one ases that takes up the full figure

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)

    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

#hide the spines,ticks,etc

    ax.axis('off')

#Display the image

    ax.imshow(im_data, cmap='gray')

    plt.show()

#call the display funtion top display

display(image_file)


#Inverted Image

inverted_image=cv.bitwise_not(img)

cv.imwrite("temp/inverted.jpg",inverted_image)

display("temp/inverted.jpg")

#Binarization


def grayscale(image):
    return cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


gray_image = grayscale(img)

cv.imwrite("temp/gray.jpg", gray_image)

display("temp/gray.jpg")
```

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [ask]. you didn't search for the error message or debug your program before asking but you are required to do these things.

Comment: `height, width = im_data.shape[:2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not receive depth for gray scale images.

Return Type of [matplotlib.pyplot.imread](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html)

The image data. The returned array has shape

```
(M, N) for grayscale images.
(M, N, 3) for RGB images.
(M, N, 4) for RGBA images.
```

Comment: Then which line should be modified? Please mark that line ..